# How to read a variable in grunt config defined within the target?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm trying to configure grunt for a multi task `registerMultiTask` having a targets depending upon the different domains.

Below is the configuration example.

```
grunt.initConfig({
    log: {
        'domain_01': {
            hostName: 'www.domain1.com',
            options: {
                urls: [ 
                    '<%= hostName %>' + '/file1.js', 
                    '<%= hostName %>' + '/file2.js'
                ]
            }
        }
    }
});

grunt.registerMultiTask('log', function() {
    grunt.log.writeln('hostName = ' + this.data.hostName);
    grunt.log.writeln('urls = ' + this.data.options.urls);
});
```

So, expected result should be:

```
> grunt validation:domain_01
hostName = domain_01
urls = ['www.domain1.com/file1.js', 'www.domain1.com/file2.js']
```

I'm having toruble reading the variable `hostName` defined inside the target `domain_01`, getting the error:

> Warning: An error occurred while processing a template (hostName is
>   not defined). Use --force to continue.
>
> Aborted due to warnings.

I also tried with
 `['<%= grunt.config("log.domain_02.hostName") %>' + '/file1.js', ...]`.

It worked but it defeats the aim of making this code a generic one as I will have to change the template string on every line if I want to add another target.
How can I achieve this?

**Note:** Task `log` is just a sample task, I will be using different plugins and for that purpose I want minimum changes to it and achieve in configuration only if possible.

Answer (score 2):

### Update...

I misread a couple of key requirements in your post when providing my previous answer. I.e. This part in the title:

> ...read a variable in grunt config defined within the target?

and this too..

> ...as I will have to change the template string on every line if I want to add another target

#### Solution three

This can be achieved by:

1. Not attempting to use template strings to prefix the `hostName` in `options.urls` of each target.
2. Prefix each url with its relevant `hostName` inside the `grunt.registerMultiTask` function instead.

The following gist demonstrates this:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    'use strict';

    grunt.initConfig({

        log: {
            'domain_01': {
                hostName: 'www.domain1.com',
                options: {
                    urls: [
                        '/file1.js' //<-- Note: No reference to hostName
                    ]
                }
            },
            'domain_02': {
                hostName: 'www.domain2.com',
                options: {
                    urls: [
                        '/file1.js',
                        '/file2.js'
                    ]
                }
            },
            'domain_03': {
                hostName: 'www.domain3.com',
                options: {
                    urls: [
                        '/file1.js',
                        '/file2.js',
                        '/file3.js'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerMultiTask('log', function() {
        var hostName = this.data.hostName,
            urls = this.data.options.urls.map(function (url) {
                return hostName + url;
            });

        grunt.log.writeln('hostName = ' + hostName);
        grunt.log.writeln('urls = ' + urls);
    });
};
```

**Results**

1. Running `$ grunt log:domain_01` via the CLI returns:

```c#
hostName = www.domain1.com
urls = www.domain1.com/file1.js
```

2. `$ grunt log:domain_02` returns:

```c#
hostName = www.domain2.com
urls = www.domain2.com/file1.js,www.domain2.com/file2.js
```

2. And `$ grunt log:domain_03` returns:

```c#
hostName = www.domain3.com
urls = www.domain3.com/file1.js,www.domain3.com/file2.js,www.domain3.com/file3.js
```

---

### Previous Answer...

You could setup as follows:

#### Solution one

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({

        hostName: 'www.domain1.com', //<-- Define the default hostname

        log: {
            'domain_01': {
                hostName: '<%= hostName %>',
                options: {
                    urls: [
                        '<%= hostName %>' + '/file1.js',
                        '<%= hostName %>' + '/file2.js'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerMultiTask('log', function() {
        grunt.log.writeln('hostName = ' + this.data.hostName);
        grunt.log.writeln('urls = ' + this.data.options.urls);
    });
};
```

***Note*** the addition of the `hostName` key plus default value.

---

#### Solution two

You may wish to consider also utilizing the [grunt.option](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option) API if the `hostName` value is likely to change in the future, therefore providing even more generic code. For example:

module.exports = function(grunt) {

```
    grunt.initConfig({

        // Notice this time we also accept an optional value and a default.
        hostName: grunt.option('hostName') || 'www.domain1.com',

        log: {
            'domain_01': {
                hostName: '<%= hostName %>',
                options: {
                    urls: [
                        '<%= hostName %>' + '/file1.js',
                        '<%= hostName %>' + '/file2.js'
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerMultiTask('log', function() {
        grunt.log.writeln('hostName = ' + this.data.hostName);
        grunt.log.writeln('urls = ' + this.data.options.urls);
    });
};
```

**1** Running solution two via the CLI as follows:

`$ grunt log`

reports:

```c#
hostName = www.domain1.com
urls = www.domain1.com/file1.js,www.domain1.com/file2.js
```

*Note* the default value is used as no option flag is provided.

**2** Whilst running solution two via the CLI with an options flag as follows:

`$ grunt log --hostName=www.domain2.com`

... reports:

```c#
hostName = www.domain2.com
urls = www.domain2.com/file1.js,www.domain2.com/file2.js
```

*Note* the options flag value is reported.